# R slide window through tibble

Tags: r, postgresql, tidyverse, sliding-window, dbplyr

I got a simple question that I cannot figure out solutions. 
Also, I didn't find an answer that I understand.

Imagine I got this data frame

```
(ts <- tibble(
+   a = LETTERS[1:10],
+   b = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2,5))
+ ))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   a         b
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 A         1
 2 B         1
 3 C         1
 4 D         1
 5 E         1
 6 F         2
 7 G         2
 8 H         2
 9 I         2
10 J         2
```

What I want is simple. I want to build a df with the column `b` indexing a sliding window which sizes n f the column `a`.

The output can be something like this:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
      b a    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 A B  
2     1 B C  
3     1 C D  
4     1 D E  
5     2 F G  
6     2 G H  
7     2 H I  
8     2 I J
```

I don't care if the column `a` contains an array (nest values).
I just need a new data frame based on the sliding window.

Since this operation will run in a relational database I'd like a function compatible with DBI-PostgresSQL.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'b', create the new column based on the `lead` of 'a', remove the `NA` rows with `na.omit`

```
library(dplyr)
ts %>% 
    group_by(b) %>% 
    mutate(a2 = lead(a)) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    na.omit %>%
    select(b, everything())
# A tibble: 8 x 3
#      b a     a2   
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 A     B    
#2     1 B     C    
#3     1 C     D    
#4     1 D     E    
#5     2 F     G    
#6     2 G     H    
#7     2 H     I    
#8     2 I     J
```

---

If `lead` doesn't works, then just remove the first element, append `NA` at the end in the `mutate` step

```
ts %>%  
     group_by(b) %>% 
     mutate(a2 = c(a[-1], NA)) %>%
     ungroup %>% 
     na.omit %>% 
     select(b, everything())
```